# Efficient and faster way of constructing network graph from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, networkx

I have a dataset with fields movie_id, genres. Total number of rows in the dataset is 103110. Now I am trying to construct a network graph of movies where two movies are connected if they belong to similar genres. Since it is a large dataset its taking too much time.

```
movie_id | genres 
 1         ab,bc,ca     
 5         dd,aa       
 20        ab,zz      
 22        aa,bb       
 33        cc,rr
```

In this eg. movie 1 and movie 20 will have an edge, similarly movie 5 and movie 22 will have an edge in the network. I am using the following code but it is taking too much time. please suggest some faster approach.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


rdf = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")

g=nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(rdf['movieId'].tolist())

eg=[]

for i,r in rdf.iterrows():
    for j,r1 in rdf.iterrows():
           if r['genres'] in r1['genres']:
              eg1.append((r['movieId'],r1['movieId']))



g.add_edges_from(eg)

nx.write_adjlist(g,"movie_graph.csv")
```

Comment: Probably you shouldnt use a pandas at all

Comment: using iteration can take long time. Maybe first create file with results and later use this file to create graph - you will see which part take so long. OR maybe you should use `groupby('movieId')` and then you would have all users with the same `movieId`. But still it would need loop to create all connections between users.